Force regular Audio API for games
The games sound very tiny compared to regular speaker experience you get when using the phone because Android switches audio API to low level one for gaming.
Regular API is used when you screen record during gaming, and it sounds full, rich, and spatial with Dolby Atmos on.
Genshin Impact has Audio API compatibility mode option to force regular API, but not all games provide this.
So, is there any method, app, or ADB command to force regular API for gaming?
